# How to integrate boost asio with libjuice? (P2P NAT Traversal library)

Tags: networking, boost-asio, p2p, nat

I need to have a P2P connectionn running on two hosts on different networks and for them to send a video stream sustained by a boost.asio context. Has there been any effort to have an ICE agent run on a Boost.asio context? If the overhead of running the agent on a separate boost thread is too high then I won't even try. Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correclty there are (at least) two way: you need a (relatively) simple C++ wrapper for a kind of an ICE agent with semantics akin to libjuice. It will take a reference to external io_context, contain C libjuice's agent instance inside, provide a way to set callbacks, run dedicated thread for libjuice's agent, processe any libjuice callbacks and post your library user's callbacks to passed external io_context.
Second would be to write an io_object/io_service pair with io_object having some async_* methods following ASIO paradigm.